Identify this set: sealed bag with azure, dark blue, and white parts

I have bags of legos I got at a garage sale but can’t find the manuals.
How can I figure out what set they are to?

This question is similar to: How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is one more case of How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags? .
One of the unique bricks here is the 6x4 wedge plate, which only one set has in Medium Azure colour: 41682 "Heartlake city school".
